# Mix two sub-lists into one List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have two list of the same size:

In the list "a" I have

```
Position[0] = 1,2,3
Position[1] = 7,8,9
Position[2] = 13,14,15
Position[3] = 19,20,21
```

In the list "b" I have

```
Position[0] = 4,5,6
Position[1] = 10,11,12
Position[2] = 16,17,18
Position[3] = 22,23,24
```

What I'm trying to do is mix both list to get this:

```
Position[0] = 1,2,3,4,5,6
Position[1] = 7,8,9,10,11,12
Position[2] = 13,14,15,16,17,18
Position[3] = 19,20,21,22,23,24
```

I have tried this

```
public List<Object[]> getMixedList() {
 List a, b;
 a = getLista();
 b = getListb();
 List<Object[]> ab = new ArrayList<Object[]>(a);
 ab.addAll(b);
 return ab
}
```

But What I get is this

```
Position[0] = 1,2,3
Position[1] = 7,8,9
Position[2] = 13,14,15
Position[3] = 19,20,21
Position[4] = 4,5,6
Position[5] = 10,11,12
Position[6] = 16,17,18
Position[7] = 22,23,24
```

I've been working with loops but can't figure out how to do it beacuse when I make the second for to iterate the list "b" it adds the whole list b in the fist position of the list a and so on.

Any clue will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; ++i) {
   Object[] aContent = a.get(i);
   Object[] bContent = b.get(i);
   ... add your code to merge the content ..
   ab.add(mergedResult);
}
```

Comment: I did that already, the problem is that i don't know how to concatenate both objects: I have the elements of list "a" in position[0] and I have the elements of of list "b" in position zero, but how do I merge them? I have tried add.(aContent); add.(bContent); but it place it down instead of mix it.

Comment: I'll give you a clue. `mergedResult` is another array of objects and you must move the contents of a and b into it one by one.

Comment: Finished, I used a matrix to save the elements one by one and 2 for's to iterate first a and then b. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

[addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) does not append corresponding elements of `Collections` rather it appends them to the end of the `Collection`.

You need to iterate through the first collection, create a new array and copy the elements of both corresponding arrays into the new array *before* setting that as the new array element.

As arrays are fixed in size, you can use [System#arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to create a new array large enough to accommodate entries from corresponding array elements.

```
List<Object[]> getMergedList(List<Object[]> list1, List<Object[]> list2) {
    List<Object[]> mergedList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {

        Object[] objects1 = list1.get(i);
        Object[] objects2 = list2.get(i);

        int length1 = objects1.length;
        int length2 = objects2.length;
        Object[] mergedArray = new Object[length1 + length2];
        System.arraycopy(objects1, 0, mergedArray, 0, length1);
        System.arraycopy(objects2, 0, mergedArray, length1, length2);

        mergedList.add(mergedArray);
    }

    return mergedList;
}
```

Comment: I iterate the list "a" and get the elements of the position of both lists, but then I don't know how to merge them in an object to add them to my final list.

Comment: Thanks anyway, perhaps yours is more efficent, by the way I didn't know what you were talking about with the System.arraycopy until the netbeans suggested it instead of my for.

Answer (score 1):

`addAll` appends the elements to the end of the `ArrayList`. It is just concatenation in your case.

The example is a bit hard to work with since arrays are fixed length. You'd better off using a list of lists, or maybe a `Map` of `List`s in this case. If you are stuck in the current format, then you need to use a new list of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over both loops at the same time.  I don't want to give you more information, because this sounds like a homework problem.